# “Posts by Category” or “Posts by Categories”?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Google search results:

"posts by categories" — 442 000
"posts by category"   — 2 820 000

Usually there are many posts and many categories, but many people do something like that: http://heteconomist.com/all-posts-by-category/  Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People who write *by categories* think about posts sorted into a number of categories, people who write *by category* think about *category* as the criterion for sorting. Either form is acceptable, but I think the singular is mildly preferred in formal discourse.

Comment: Why not *by **a** category*?

Comment: *Posts by category* tells you that multiple categories, probably overlapping and possibly incommensurable, are represented, but *posts by **a** category* tell you nothing at all. If you are using only one category, subcategorized along a scale, you give the name of the category: *Posts by age* or *posts by source* or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

"posts by categories" is incorrect.

"posts by category" assumes multiple categories, else it's meaningless.

One would also say, for example, "posts by gender" not "posts by genders".